# Parsing asmx returned JSON on Android

Tags: android, asp.net, json

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 Webservice (asmx) that returns what appears to be valid JSON.  I have validated the returned JSON using an online validator (JSONLint . com) and it says it is valid.  I can not figure out how to parse this string.

```
{
    "d": "{\"returnType\":\"authToken\",\"returnData\":\"b1ec28b8-3fca-427a-bbce-8802fb95d94b\"}"
}
```

Below is my code.

```
public static JSONObject DotNetJSONResponse(String raw) throws Exception {
    JSONObject joRaw;
    try {
        joRaw = new JSONObject(raw);
        JSONObject joD = joRaw.getJSONObject("d");
        return joD;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
public static JSONObject DotNetJSONResponse(String raw) throws Exception {
JSONObject joRaw;
  try {
      joRaw = new JSONObject(raw);
      String str1 = joRaw.getString("d");
      JSONObject joD = new JSONObject(str1);
      return joD;
      } catch (JSONException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. In your sample response, **d** is a an attribute, not a JSONObject. So have to parse the string first, then convert the d string as a JSONObject.

```
public static JSONObject DotNetJSONResponse(String raw) throws Exception {
    JSONObject joRaw;
    try {
        joRaw = new JSONObject(raw);
        String t=joRaw.getString("d");
        System.out.println(t);                  \\< ---------- 
        JSONObject joD = new JSONObject(t);
        return joD;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  t = {"returnType":"authToken","returnData":"b1ec28b8-3fca-427a-bbce-8802fb95d94b"}

Comment: whats the output? u got any exception?

Comment: When I step thru the code, the line JSONObject joD = new JSONObject(t); appears to throw an exception.  The arrow jumps down to return null;(with no e.printStackTrace(); happening), but then returns a JSONobject to the calling line with correct data.

Comment: Ive edited the code a bit, make sure `t` gets a proper JSON string in to it.

Comment: the value in t is "{"returnType":"authToken","returnData":"b1ec28b8-3fca-427a-bbce-8802fb95d94b"}"(no quotes).  The method does return a JSONObject with the proper data, but is still getting caught in the catch.

Comment: it works perfectly in my case. Could u send me the webservice URL, if its not confidential... so that i can check it directly.